# Whitespace changes the sequence of str_match results

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

Using **str_match** at the moment, I have written a regex which extract the info after the third dash (-) in the string.

Issue is that sometimes there is a whitespace in the string, changes the output column sequence.

with space:

```
> str_match("abc -xyz-a-**want**-12341", "(\\w+)-(\\w+)-(\\w+)-(\\w+)")
     [,1]               [,2]  [,3] [,4]   [,5]   
[1,] "xyz-a-want-12341" "xyz" "a"  "want" "12341"
```

without space:

```
str_match("abc-xyz-a-**want**-12341", "(\\w+)-(\\w+)-(\\w+)-(\\w+)")
     [,1]             [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5]  
[1,] "abc-xyz-a-want" "abc" "xyz" "a"  "want"
>
```

Can I resolve this just by changing my regex or should I first try to clean the whitespace (which seems unnecessary to me at this point if regex alone can handle this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue with your thought process, we could add an optional whitespace argument in each capture group.

```
library(stringr)

str_match("abc -xyz-a-want-12341","(\\w+\\s*?)-(\\w+\\s*?)-(\\w+\\s*?)-(\\w+\\s*?)")

#     [,1]              [,2]   [,3]  [,4] [,5]  
#[1,] "abc -xyz-a-want" "abc " "xyz" "a"  "want"

str_match("abc-xyz-a-want-12341", "(\\w+\\s*?)-(\\w+\\s*?)-(\\w+\\s*?)-(\\w+\\s*?)")

#     [,1]             [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5]  
#[1,] "abc-xyz-a-want" "abc" "xyz" "a"  "want"
```

As mentioned in the comments, whitespace could be present anywhere in the string. In such case, we can just extract everything

```
str_match(" abc -xy z-a-wa nt-123 41","(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)")
```

Comment: Thank mate. The example you shared does seem to work. but if i try it by adding a few spaces, it gives out NA. 

```> str_match(" abc -xy z-a-wa nt-123 41","(\\w+\\s*?)-(\\w+\\s*?)-(\\w+\\s*?)-(\\w+\\s*?)")
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  ```

Comment: @mike If your spaces do not have any pattern then why to include anything at all? Capture everything between two `-`. `str_match(" abc -xy z-a-wa nt-123 41","(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)")`